# CSV file input not working together with set field value step in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a very simple Pentaho Kettle transformation that causes a strange error. It consists of reading a field `X` from a CSV, add a field `Y`, set `Y=X` and finally write it back to another CSV.

Here you can see the steps and the configuration for them:

[image: Configuration.]

You can also download the ktr file from [here](http://justpaste.it/nx60). The input data is just this:

```
1
2
3
```

When I run this transformation, I get this error message:

```
ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException:
Error writing line

Error writing field content to file

Y Number : There was a data type error: the data type of [B object [[B©b4136a] does not correspond to value meta [Number]



at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFiIeOutput.writeRowToFile(TextFiIeOutput.java:273)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFileOutput.processRow(TextFiIeOutput.java:195)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
atjava.Iang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException:
Error writing field content to file

Y Number : There was a data type error: the data type of [B object [[B©b4136a] does not correspond to value meta [Number]


at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFiIeOutput.writeField(TextFileOutput.java:435)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFiIeOutput.writeRowToFile(TextFiIeOutput.java:249)
3 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleVaIueException:
Y Number : There was a data type error: the data type of [B object [[B©b4136a] does not correspond to value meta [Number]

at org.pentaho.di.core.row.vaIue.VaIueMetaBase.getBinaryString(VaIueMetaBase.java:2185)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFiIeOutput.formatField(TextFiIeOutput.java:290)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.textfiIeoutput.TextFiIeOutput.writeField(TextFileOutput.java:392)
4 more
```

All of the above lines start with `2015/09/23 12:51:18 - Text file output.0 -`, but I edited it out for brevity. I think the relevant, and confusing, part of the error message is this:

```
Y Number : There was a data type error: the data type of [B object [[B©b4136a] does not correspond to value meta [Number]
```

Some further notes:

- If I bypass the set field value step by using the lower hop instead, the transformation finish without errors. This leads me to believe that it is the set field value step that causes the problem.
- If I replace the CSV file input with a data frame with the same data (`1,2,3`) everything works just fine.
- If I replace the file output step with a dummy the transformation finish without errors. However, if I preview the dummy, it causes a similar error and the field `Y` has the value `<null>` on all three  rows.
- Before I created this MCVE I got the error on all sorts of seemingly random steps, even when there was no file output present. So I do not think this is related to the file output.
- If I change the format from Number to Integer, nothing changes. But if I change it to string the transformations finish without errors, and I get this output:

  ```
  X;Y
  1;[B@49e96951
  2;[B@7b016abf
  3;[B@1a0760b0
  ```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: One workaround that I just found is to remove the add constant and set field value steps, and instead use a formula step, with new field set to `Y` and formula to `[x]`.

Comment: Would still be nice to know what is causing this problem, though.

Comment: Have you tried turning lazy conversion off? That's frequently a cause of weird errors with text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of lazy conversion.  Turn it off.  This is behaving exactly as designed - although admittedly the error and user experience could be improved.

Lazy conversion must not be used when you need to access the field value in your transformation.  That's exactly what it *does*.  The default should probably be off rather than on.

If your field is going directly to a database, then use it and it will be faster.

You can even have "partially lazy" streams, where you use lazy conversion for speed, but then use select values step, to "un-lazify" the fields you want to access, whilst the remainder remain lazy.

Cunning huh?

Comment: All these years later this is still good advice! - Thanks man, I thought I was going nuts.